# Equivalent color for \colorbox{gray} as for \cellcolor[gray]{0.8}

Tags: tables, color

In my table I have used `\cellcolor[gray]{0.8}` and I would like to mark some words in my text with the same color. I have tried `\colorbox{gray}`, but the resulting box in the text is too dark. How can I get the same grey-color as in the table?

Comment: `\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.8}` and `\colorbox{gray}` would do the job?

Comment: There are some more levels of grey in my table. Do I have to specify a separate function for each level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arguments to `\cellcolor` are just passed to `\color` internally so that it colours the panel of the specified colour so

```
\cellcolor[gray]{0.8}
```

just calls

```
\color[gray]{0.8}
```

and you may use that directly.

Comment: Hello David, how shoul I use it to get the same color for the box? I have unsuccessfully tried: `\colorbox{\color[gray]{0.8}}{text}`

Comment: I have tried `\colorbox[gray]{0.8}{text}` but the colors are not the same...

Comment: @JohnnyB well I wrote that code and I can promise you that neither `\colorbox` nor `\cellcolor` do anything with colour values at all, both just set things up then call `\color` with the supplied values.

Comment: `\colorbox{\color[gray]{0.8}}{text}` no! `\colorbox[gray]{0.8}{text}` `\colorbox` is like `\cellcolor` and just passes its arguments to `\color`

Answer (score 4):

You can try `gray!<percentage>` syntax like `gray!20`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
  \colorbox{gray!20}{gray!20}\color{gray!80} some text
\end{document}
```

[image]